# Membership Reboot create/edit new tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ravendb, membershipreboot

In [MembershipReboot Documentation](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/wiki/Multi-Tenancy) described ability use few tenants in app.

```
<membershipReboot multiTenant="true" defaultTenant="SomeName" />
```

But there are no examples how to implement crud for tenants using ravendb. Please share link or provide example if you have.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean is there a way to CRUD Tenant objects, there isn't any because there isn't any such thing as a tenant object.  It's simply a string that operates as a discriminator in the database.  You need to pass in your own tenant string.

If you mean creating a user there isn't much too it.  You have to implement a RavenDB Repository. (see here [Sample RavenDb implementation](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/tree/master/samples/NoSql/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot.RavenDb)), then simply call the create method on the UserAccountService

```
        var securitySettings = new SecuritySettings
        {
            AllowLoginAfterAccountCreation = true,
            MultiTenant = true,
        };

        var config = new MembershipRebootConfiguration<HierarchicalUserAccount>(securitySettings);
        var repository = new RavenUserAccountRepository("");

        var uas = new UserAccountService<HierarchicalUserAccount>(config, repository);

        var userAccount = uas.CreateAccount("tenant_id", "username", "password", "test@test.com");
```